# Does join happen with empty foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose I have `posts`, `post_tags`, and `post_categories` tables. On the post's page I take the id from url and need to find the post's info with the associated tables. Tags and categories are optional, so, some posts have neither tags, nor categories.

**Q1** If the post does not have matching rows in post_tags and post_categories tables, will the join "happen", and will it have the same resource usage, in comparison with if the rows would exist?

**Q2** If the join happens, will it be better practice if I make a first query, taking the post's type, as from the type I can check if it has tags and/or categories or no, so can choose to make a join query or just find the info of the post without even trying to join to other tables?
I think that, though having one query and fetching all data is better from making multiple queries, but maybe with the first query finding out the exact type, for posts without tags and/or post, it will be less load on the db.

posts table has about a few millions rows.

**EDIT**

I am making LEFT JOIN

Tables structure

```
posts table
id, title, content

post_categories
id, post_id, category_id,

post_tags
id, post_id, tag_id,

categories
id, name

tags
id, name
```

Thanks

Comment: __Q1__: Which `JOIN`? There are different types of `JOIN` in SQL. __Q2__: depends of what you want. Conclusion: please, post your tables structure and what is your full issue (i.e. what are you trying to achieve) instead of doing premature optimization.

Comment: See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of JOINs I use with covers all scenarios: `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

- `INNER JOIN` requires the `ON` validation to true, otherwise it removes the row from result
- `LEFT JOIN` doesn't require the `ON` validation to be true, but will treat the columns of failed table as `NULL`

In your case, I'd most likely use `LEFT JOIN` and act accordingly if the tags and the likes are `NULL` or not.

Have the `FROM` table to be where you *know* there will be rows. Do not use `FROM tags` for instance since everything will be based on rows that might not always exist.